# What is the difference between cast operator and suffixing in C?

Tags: c

If I have these constants `1 + 2.3`, what is the difference between this `(float)1 + 2.3` and this `1f + 2.3` ?

Comment: `1(float) + 2.3` is a syntax error. Can you please show us 2 valid expressions that you are confused about?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the second one won't compile...

Comment: Well my book, C Primer Plus by Prata states: "...it is possible for you to demand the precise type conversion that you want or else document that you know you’re making a type conversion. The method for doing this is called a cast and consists of preceding the quantity with the name of the desired type in parentheses. The parentheses and type name together constitute a cast operator.
mice = (int) 1.6 + (int) 1.7; ..." "...To cause a small
constant to be treated as type long , you can append an l (lowercase L ) or L as a suffix...."

Answer (score 2):

So, let's look at some cases:

1. `1 + 2.3`, which is an integer plus a double.
2. `1f + 2.3`, which is a float plus a double.
3. `1. + 2.3`, which is a double plus a double.

In all three of these cases, the first argument either already is, or will be promoted to a double. Additionally, the result of these expressions will always be a double.

Comment: No promotions in the last one... ;-)

Comment: Well the only thing additional I would say is that `(float) 1` is a float, and then it gets promoted to a double for the math.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `1.f` you create a float number in memory.
When you write `(float)1`, you create an integer number in memory, but this number will be interpreted like a float number in the expression (casting).